# Chromium freezes on start on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, chromium

On start Chromium freezes completly and does not respond afterwards.

`lspci | grep -i vga` says:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Using Chromium 55.0.2883.87 on (L)Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit).

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have some solution too. Seems, the problem is with GPU acceleration. But, because Chromium freezes, you cant access Settings->Advanced settings to disable hardware acceleration.

So first you need to run browser with disabled GPU:

```
$ chromium-browser --disable-gpu
```

And then you can make settings permanent in Advanced settings.

Comment: Worked for me on 14.04